# Parsing API results on Android with Retrofit and Jackson or Gson

Tags: android, jackson, gson, retrofit

I am trying to parse the results of an API call which returns a unique first property.

```
{
   "AlwaysDifferent12345": {
       "fixedname1" : "ABC1",
       "fixedname2" : "ABC2"   
   }
}
```

I am using retrofit2 and jackson/gson and cannot figure out how to cope with dynamic property names within the retrofit2 framework. The following works fine

```
data class AlwaysDifferentDTO(
    @JsonProperty("AlwaysDifferent12345") val alwaysDifferentEntry: AlwaysDifferentEntry
)
```

I have tried

```
data class AlwaysDifferentDTO(
    @JsonProperty
    val response: Map<String,  AlwaysDifferentEntry>
)
```

But this returns errors Can not instantiate value of type... The return value from the API is fixed i.e. map<string, object>.

I have read you can write a deserializer but it looks like I need to deserialize the whole object when all I want to do is just ignore the string associated with the response.

I have read
https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/set-dynamic-serializedname-annotation-for-gson-data-class/14758
and several other answers. Given unique properties names are quite common it would be nice to understand how people deal with this when using retrofit2

Thanks

Comment: You don't need the `AlwaysDifferentDTO` wrapper since your JSON _is_ a map already. Deserialize it as `Map<String, WhateverYouNeedHere>` where `WhateverYouNeedHere` is your class that can deal with `fixedname1` and `fixedname2`.

Comment: Many apologises if I am miss understanding but isn't this what you are saying. I think I am misunderstanding. I am just trying to deserialize Map<String, Object> where string is AlwaysDifferent12345 and object is a complex object

Comment: Yeah, this is why you need a map and the answer in the link you provided also tells you so, merely deserialize it typed as above: it will return a map with a single entry (key=`AlwaysDifferent12345`, value=_something from the above_). If you're using Retrofit, Retrofit can parameterize the type itself (it has enough information from the interface method declaration), so it will be easy. I believe `interface IMyApi { Call<Map<String, WhateverYouNeedHere>> call(); }` (hope no typos here) is just what you're looking for.

Comment: Additionally, if I'm not mistaken, in Gson (if you're going to use it) the Jackson `@JsonProperty` counter-part is `@SerializedName` that should be used with the `@field:` qualifier in Kotlin that tells kotlinc to put the annotation right to the backing fields Gson works with.

Comment: Thanks for your patience, changing the argument in Retrofit work like a charm. Was not seeing the fun in Kotlin yesterday.
 "@GET
    fun getAPI(
        @Url url: String): Single<Map<String,AlwaysDifferentDTO>>"

Comment: No problem, glad I could help you.

Answer (score 0):

Because the `JSON` doesn't have a 1-to-1 mapping `Jackson` can't map it automatically using `annotations`. You are going to need to make your own `Deserializer`.

In this tutorial you can learn how to create your own custom `Deserializer` for `Jackson`.  https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialization

In the tutorial you will see the first line under the `deserialize` function is

`JsonNode node = jp.getCodec().readTree(jp);`

using this line you can get the JSON node as a whole and once you have it you can call this function

`JsonNode AlwaysDifferent12345Node = node.findParent("fixedname1");`

Now that you have that node you can retrieve its value like shown in the rest of the tutorial. Once you have all the values you can return a new instance of the `AlwaysDifferentDTO` data class.

Comment: I have read this article  but does this means I have to write something that deserializing the whole object?  which seem a lot of work when I can use a data class with @SerializeName/@PropertyName for all of the other objects. (There are 10  types on the result)

Comment: Your problem is you can't tell the difference between `AlwaysDifferent12345` and  `AlwaysDifferent12346` now if you were able to control this I would change it at the source. But if you can't I don't see how you would expect it, to just figure it out. The two `annotations` you listed require constant strings. If `AlwaysDifferent12345` is not a constant then you can't use them.